# Unidentified index while echoing out else

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and i've been learning PhP like a week ago so please bear with me.

While i was trying to echo out an else statement if any variable in the POST request is different or not set.

```html
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
<p> <input type="radio" name="language" value="PHP"> PHP <br>
<input type="radio" name="language" value="RUBY"> RUBY <br>
<input type="radio" name="language" value="HTML"> HTML  <br>
 </p>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

process.php

```html
<?php
$lang = $_POST['language'];
if (isset($lang)) {
 echo $lang;
}
else {
 echo 'Buzz off';
}

?>
```

While its showing error like :

> Notice: Undefined index: language in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/process.php on line 2

Please help :)

Comment: so, this going to be voted out as a typo also?

Comment: Yeah I think they'll downvote it  for being a typo. I don't think people know what a typo is anymore. At most, this should be considered a  duplicate of that `Undefined index` question.

Comment: @Phiter right... [deja vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49391045/) - the "new" way now? if that's the way it's going to be, then Stack is on its way out.

Comment: Are you trying to visit `process.php` without submitting it from the form page? If so, you'll get the notice. You can fix it by doing what Phiter said.

Comment: @Phiter *heh* agreed man

Comment: While answering the question helps Jaasus with his specific problem, I still think it should be closed as duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to get an undefined array index and put it into a variable, and this will throw an exception.
You should check if the array key `isset` before you try to put it in a variable, like this:

```
if ($_POST['language']) {
    $lang = $_POST['language'];
    echo $lang;
}
else {
    echo 'Buzz off';
}
```

If you are using PHP7, you can use the [Null coalescing operator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).

```
$lang = $_POST['language'] ?? 'Buzz off';
echo $lang;
```